# Adding elif statement into generator notation

Tags: python, statements

I´m trying to implement generator notation into my code, specifically into my **str**() method. This is what I have so far and now I need to add "elif" statement there, but not sure how to type it into this generator notation. Can you help?

```
def __str__(self):
    lines = []
    for sub_list in self.tab:
        lines.append(' '.join([str(item) for item in sub_list if not isinstance(item, set) else '.']))
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

Comment: You can't. is the 'else' even valid? Just don't do it in a one-liner

Comment: What is the typical input, and what is the expected output, and what might your `elif` condition be?  As it is the question is missing a lot of vital details which isn't likely to produce an answer you want (and people who have answered already might possibly got some wrong assumptions).

Answer (score 2):

You had the order wrong:

```
def __str__(self):
    lines = []
    for sub_list in self.tab:
        lines.append(' '.join([str(item) if not isinstance(item, set) else '.' for item in sub_list ]))
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

The general structure of your list comprehension is

```
[somefunction(item) for item in sublist].
```

Using `if` as you did:

```
[somefunction(item) for item in sublist if <some_condition on item>]
```

means that you only include `somefunction(item)` if `some_condition` is satisfied. There can't be any `elif` here, as there is only one choice: include in the resulting list or not.

You want to generate an output for each of your items, so you don't need an `if` clause like that. But `somefunction(item)` can be the result of the evaluation of the ternary operator `str(item) if not isinstance(item, set) else '.'`.

Comment: Might be worth it to explain that what the OP had filters the elements of the iterable, while this uses a ternary expression as the value.

Comment: but that's still a ternary operator, the OP asked for an 'elif' in it.

Answer (score 0):

`if else` constructs go before `for item in sub_list` in a list comprehension.

```
sub_list = [{1}, [1], {2, 3}]

lines = []
lines.append(' '.join([str(item) if not isinstance(item, set) else '.' for item in sub_list ]))
print(lines) #Output: ['. [1] .']
```

Adding an elif can be done by chaining the conditional expressions, though there is no elif keyword directly supported in conditional expressions. Example:

```
sub_list = [{1}, [1], {2, 3}]
lines = []
lines.append(' '.join([str(item) if not isinstance(item, set) else '.' if len(item) == 1 else '!' for item in sub_list ]))
#similar to elif '.' if len(item) == 1 else '!'
print(lines) #Output: ['. [1] !']
```